# How do I download Office Sway album/presentation photos in bulk?

Tags: office-online, bulk-download, office-sway

I'm looking at a Office Sway and it's used as an album, the only problem is that I can't directly download the photos in bulk. The photos don't have their own unique URL; is there any way to download the photos in bulk without having to download them individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As of 19-07-2017, this is currently not possible.**

Given that the URLs of the images follow this pattern:

```
https://eus-www.sway-cdn.com/s/SWAY_LINK/images/IMAGE_LINK
```

`IMAGE_LINK` is unique to each image so recursive retrieval is nearly impossible. I've even tried using `wget` using the command:

```
wget --spider -r --no-parent --no-check-certificate https://eus-www.sway-cdn.com/s/SWAY_LINK/images/
```

But this link cannot be directly accessed and therefore is a broken link.

According to Jason, a Sway engineer:

> Unfortunately, not without using something like Fiddler to record a list of all the images that get downloaded when you navigate through the Sway.

This means that the only way to retrieve the original images of a Sway, you have to access each image one-by-one when navigate the Sway, which is extremely time-consuming.